# Set dropdown list default value or use value from model

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a grid that uses an external form to do the editing/adding. I used as a starting point [this](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/external-editing/) example. The form has a dropdown list. The `[data]` comes from a list of objects that have `text` and `value`.

I have tried and failed to do both of these things:

- Set the default value for the dropdown list. All I managed to do is to insert a duplicate row into the dropdown, that is indeed selected but it is also present twice. I looked at [this](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/default-item/) example when doing it. Second example with the list of objects.
- When adding a new row into the grid set the default value (for the same dropdown) on the model itself. The result is that the value set for the dropdown is completely ignored.

Can someone give me an example to this? Thanks.

Code for the first thing I've tried:

```
public arrayOfObjects:Array<SomeClass> = [
    SomeClass.staticList.object1,
    SomeClass.staticList.object2,
    SomeClass.staticList.object3,
    SomeClass.staticList.object4
];

defaultObject:SomeClass = SomeClass.staticList.object2 //I want the second as default.
```

Dropdown in the template uses these:

```
    <kendo-dropdownlist formControlName='theObject'
        [data]="arrayOfObjects" 
        [textField]="'text'"
        [valueField]="'value'"
        [valuePrimitive]="false"
        [defaultItem]='defaultObject'
        [(ngModel)]="theObject" >
```

Dropdown contents:

- object2
- object1
- object2 (yes twice)
- object3
- object4

Code for the second thing i've tried:

```
public addHandler() {
    var newRow = new RowModel();
    newReport.theObject = SomeClass.staticList.object2;
    this.editDataItem = newRow;

    this.isNew = true;
}
```

Nothing happens in this case. The dropdown remains empty.

**Solution**

The problem was that I didn't have a separate variable for ngModel. I thought for some reason that if I specify for ngModel the name of the FormControl it would magically work. It didn't. So I just created a separate variable to hold the currently selected value and it works. Thanks.

Comment: could you provide a reproduction of your code at https://plnkr.co/ ? That makes things way easier to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `defaultItem` setting of the DropDown is used to add a filler in case no item is selected from the list, like "Select an item...".

To accomplish what you're trying to do try this:

```
<kendo-dropdownlist
    [data]="listItems"
    textField="text"
    valueField="value"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedItem"
>

public listItems = [
    { text: "Option1", value: 1 },
    { text: "Option2", value: 2 },
    { text: "Option3", value: 3 }
];

public selectedItem = this.listItems[1];
```

Comment: Thanks this actually works. I created a separate property for the selectedItem and it works now. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by separate property. Do you mean adding selectedItem property for every object in listItems?

Comment: He means adding a property (`selectedItem`) to the component that will store the currently selected item, like in my example. He used the work 'separate' to indicate that this property will be dedicated to this use.